# How to change database without affecting yii?

Tags: database, database-design, yii

First I created a database, then a model and CRUD. When I try to change the database properties, I get an error. What are the steps to change the database to the desired schema? For example add a column, change int to varchar, or change a column name. I am new to [yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

Comment: Punctuation is always a nice thing to use. Perhaps try to not use 10 exclamation marks in your question. You will have a much better response if you at least try to formulate it politely.

Comment: thanks u advice please correct me if am wrong any where

Comment: Much better :) Removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean here.

If you mean just changing some columns and tables then you can do this from anywhere, mysql command line (if you're using it) phpMyAdmin, wherever you like to do DB administration from. Yii will automatically pick up any changes to the database schema when it accesses those tables.

If you mean a way to change some columns and attributes from within Yii then you can use the [DBCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand) to issue `dropColumn`, `alterColumn` etc.

If you mean a way to track changes to the schema, then you need to be looking at [Migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration#creating-migrations) and source controlling them

If none of those fit then I'm not sure what you're asking for, sorry.